# ASP.net SMTP unable to send email

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, smtp

I have an asp.net 4.0 website (IIS7.5) and I'm using the PasswordRecovery control for a forgot password form. When I run the site locally it works fine, emails are sent. However, when I run the site from  my vps (also IIS7.5), I get an error message when trying to send the email. There's nothing in the server's event log.

My PasswordRecovery aspx code is as follows:

```
 <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server"       
            CssClass="mediumText">
            <MailDefinition From="noreply@x.com"   BodyFileName="~/EmailTemplates/PasswordRecovery.txt" />
```

My web.config mail settings are as follows:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="noreply@x.com">
        <network host="smtp.123-reg.co.uk" password="x" userName="x" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

I can confirm that I'm able to ping smtp.123-reg.co.uk from the server. I know the username and password are correct because the same config file works when I run the website on my laptop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your VPS host blocking port 25? Can you telnet smtp.123-reg.co.uk 25 and reach the SMTP server?

Comment: Reality check - you talk a lot about waht does not work, but you do not tll us the error message you get... which likely contains the expkllanation of your problem. In clear text. Please add the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was due to firewall access to the smtp server. Work-around was to configure local host as an smtp server